# tf.keras - Apply specific layers only to specific features

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'll explain better: I want to apply some layers inside my model to some features, use other layers on other features, and finally use the outputs of both of these on some final layers.

In particular: I have a dataset with some categorical features that I have One Hot Encoded, and then 50 other numerical columns representing 10 years (each with the same 5 features).

What I'd like to do is:

1. Run the dummies of the categorical (and their interactions) on some Dense layers;
2. Run an LSTM on the numerical yearly features to predict the 11<sup>th</sup> year;
3. Finally mix the outputs of 1. and 2. into some final Dense layers and then pass them to the final Dense(1), which will be the output of my regression.

> My question is: *How can I make some specific features to go into some specific layers and how can I direct the output of these layers (along with the others analyzing other features) to some final layers that should gather all the info drawn from the previous ones?

I hope I was clear enough. Many thanks to those who'll answer.

Edit:

---

This is what I did so far, please tell me if you could come up with suggestions on how to improve it.

Ps. Input data are 100% of correct shape.

```
cat_in = k.layers.Input(shape=(X_train_p3.shape[1],), name='cat_in')
num_in = k.layers.Input(shape=(X_train_m.shape[1], X_train_m.shape[2]), name='num_in')
ovr_in = k.layers.Input(shape=(X_train_f.shape[1],), name='ovr_in')

a = k.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(cat_in)
a = k.layers.Dropout(.2)(a)
a = k.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(a)
a = k.layers.Dropout(.2)(a)
a = k.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(a)


b = k.layers.LSTM(128, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(num_in) #original --> needs changes?
b = k.layers.Dropout(.15)(b)
b = k.layers.LSTM(64, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(b)
b = k.layers.Dropout(.15)(b)
b = k.layers.LSTM(64, activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(b)
b = k.layers.Dropout(.15)(b)
b = k.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(b)
b = k.layers.Dropout(.15)(b)
b = k.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(b)


c = k.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(ovr_in)
c = k.layers.Dropout(.2)(c)
c = k.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(c)
c = k.layers.Dropout(.2)(c)
c = k.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(c)


d = k.layers.concatenate([a, b, c])
d = k.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(d)
d = k.layers.Dropout(.2)(d)
d = k.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(d)
d = k.layers.Dropout(.2)(d)
d = k.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(.1),
                   bias_regularizer=l1(.1), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(d)
out = k.layers.Dense(1)(d)


model = k.models.Model(inputs=[cat_in, num_in, ovr_in], outputs=out)

model.compile(optimizer=k.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.001, beta_1=.999, beta_2=.9999),
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['mae'])

early_stop = k.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_mae', patience=100, restore_best_weights=True)
lr_callback = k.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_mae', factor=.1**.5, patience=20, min_lr=1e-9)
```

Pps: Increasing the number of neurons do not lead to improvements.

Comment: You can feed multiple inputs to a model.  So you can feed categorical and numeric features separately.  Then it is trivial to apply a different layer to each input.  Finally, use Concatenate layer to combine the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to provide you a dummy example

```
n_sample = 100
cat_feat = 30
dense_feat = 50
lstm_timestep = 20


X_cat = np.random.randint(0,2, (n_sample,cat_feat)) 
X_dense = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample, lstm_timestep, dense_feat))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, n_sample)
print(X_cat.shape, X_dense.shape)

inp_cat = Input((cat_feat))
x_cat = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inp_cat)


inp_dense = Input((lstm_timestep, dense_feat))
x_dense = LSTM(32, activation='relu')(inp_dense)

concat = Concatenate()([x_cat, x_dense])
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(concat)
out = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model([inp_cat,inp_dense], out)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.fit([X_cat,X_dense],y, epochs=10)
```

Comment: Ciao Marco, I did build a model as such, still, that led to no improvements!
The model I show in my question actually performs worse than a simple sequential with just Dense layers! I know as a fact that there's still room for consistent improvements.

Comment: great... in most cases simple models are better then complex models... I suggest you to have a good validation strategy and take care of scaling of input and output. start from simple dense and then try to improve with rnn... and don't forget to upvote